# Loop through variables in different classes to match string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, oop, sinatra

I have a ruby (sinatra) app that I am working on, and my input is a url and if verbose or not (true or false), so basically like this:

The url would look like this: `http://localhost:4567/git.company.com&v=false` for example.

And the code to fetch those is this:

```
get '/:url' do |tool_url|
    url = params[:url].to_s
    is_verbose = params[:v].to_s
```

I have different classes separated in different files and I'm including them into my main script like this:

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib/*.rb"].each { |f| require(f) }
```

(And a sample file would be something like this), `gitlab.rb`:

```
class Gitlab
  $gitlab_token = 'TOKEN_GOES_HERE'
  def initialize(url, v)
    @@regex =~ /git.company.com/
    @@gitlab_url = url
    @@is_verbose = v
  end

  def check_gitlab(gitlab_url, is_verbose)
    _gitlab_overall = '/health_check.json?token=#{gitlab_token}'
    _gitlab_cache = '/health_check/cache.json?token=#{gitlab_token}'
    _gitlab_database = '/health_check/database.json?token=#{gitlab_token}'
    _gitlab_migrations = '/health_check/migrations.json?token=#{gitlab_token}'
    unless is_verbose = true
      CheckString.check_string_from_page('https://' + gitlab_url + gitlab_overall, 'success')
    else

    end
  end
end
```

Now, I want to be able to dynamically know which "class" to use to do a certain job based on the URL that's entered by the user, so my idea was to iterate through those classes looking for a particular variable to match with the input.

I need guidance in this because I've been stuck on this for quite some time now; I've tried so many things that I can think of, but none worked.

Disclaimer: Please bear with me here, because I'm very new to Ruby and I'm not that great in OOP languages (haven't really practiced them that much).

EDIT: I'm open to any suggestion, like if there's a different logic that's better than this, please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a hash `{ Regexp ⇒ Class }`:

```
HASH = {
  /git.company.com/ => Gitlab,
  /github.com/ => Github
}
```

and then do:

```
handler = HASH.detect { |k, _| k =~ url }.last.new
```

The above will give you an instance of the class you wanted.

*Sidenotes:*

- `is_verbose = params[:v].to_s` always results in `is_verbose` set to `truthy` value, check for `params[:v].to_s == "true"`
- `is_verbose = true` is an assignment, you wanted to use just `unless is_verbose`.

---

To make it runtime-resolving, force the plugins to a) `include Plugin` and b) declare `resolve` method. `Plugin` module should define a callback hook:

```
module Plugin
  def self.included(base)
    Registry::HASH[-> { base.resolve }] = base
  end
end
```

`resolve` method should return a regexp, the lambda is here to make it  resolved on parsing stage:

```
class PluginImpl
  include Plugin
  def resolve
    /git.company.com/
  end
end
```

And then match when needed:

```
handler = HASH.detect { |k, _| k.() =~ url }.last.new
```

Other way round would be to use [`ObjectSpace`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/ObjectSpace.html) to detect classes, including the module, or declare the [`TracePoint`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/TracePoint.html) on `base` in `included` callback to provide a direct map, but all this is overcomplicating.

Comment: I thought about making a hash.. But the thing is that, I wanted to make my app modular.. Like as in, I want the person who's writing a new "module" to define what the main app to look for... So I wanted to create an array of objects or something and if the main app matches the URL with the specified string/regex in the module then execute that.

Comment: Thanks for the update.. Just to clear a couple of things up, can you tell me where things go? Like, does the `module Plugin` go in the `main.rb` and `class PluginImpl` goes in the "module" like `gitlab.rb`? And if I already have  `module Main` in the `main.rb` this would be fine to include it there under it? Please excuse those beginner questions, I'm new to Ruby and I'm just trying to understand it better.. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm.. This looks like a great answer but pretty complicated for a beginner in Ruby like myself.. I'll mark it as the answer, but I'll have to try to get it to work some how.. Maybe an array pattern would be a bit easier..

Comment: Sorry for the delay: I do have a sleep sometimes. `Plugin` is the default interface and it’s code goes anywhere onto the path. Under “Main” is fine. `PluginImpl` is `Gitlab`, `Github`, whatever you want to be “pluggable.” `HASH` constant might reside, for instance, in your `Main` class.